# g++ with iOS sysroot and xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, gcc, g++, xcode8

With Xcode 8.0 I can cross-compile for iOS by using `sysroot`:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ \
    --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk \
    -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -arch armv7s -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 \
    helloworld.cpp
```

However, with Xcode 8.1 this falls down:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ \
    --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk \
    -miphoneos-version-min=10.1 -arch armv7s -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 \
    helloworld.cpp
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'MacOSX' but targeting 'iPhone'
In file included from helloworld.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:70:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:761:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
```

The warning that `using sysroot for 'MacOSX' but targeting 'iPhone'` seems to indicate that the `sysroot` argument is being ignored (and in the errors its clear that its using MacOSX10.12.sdk).

Have these arguments changed?  How can I specify the sysroot correctly?

Comment: I've cross-posted this on the Apple Developer Forums here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apple's gcc/g++ are just shims on top of clang/clang++, can we just use clang directly?

It turns out that works:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ \
    --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk \
    -miphoneos-version-min=10.1 -arch armv7s -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 \
    helloworld.cpp
```

Apple's gcc/g++ seem to be busted for changing the sysroot.  However we seem to be able to use the gcc-style `--sysroot` argument.  Convenient!

Curiously, if I try to use an unprefixed clang, I have to use `-isysroot`:

```
clang++ \
    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk \ 
    -miphoneos-version-min=10.1 -arch armv7s -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 \
    helloworld.cpp
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `-isysroot` with newer Xcode instead of `--sysroot`, and use a space instead of the equal sign.